# How to add the entire line into the grep result?

Tags: bash, search, grep

Right now I have 2 files:

File1:

```
120111 A
120112 B
120113 C
120114 D
120115 E
```

File2:

```
   aaa bb dd cc 120111
    ccc ss ll ee 120111
    sss cd ff ee 120111
    bbb ek lw ss 120112
    bbb kk ll ww 120112
    wwo oo kk ww 120112
    ww kkk jw ll 120113
    www kk sl if 120114
    wwk kl so as 120114
    wei kk lw pz 120115
```

I want to have an output like this:

```
   aaa bb dd cc 120111 A
    ccc ss ll ee 120111 A
    sss cd ff ee 120111 A
    bbb ek lw ss 120112 B
    bbb kk ll ww 120112 B
    wwo oo kk ww 120112 B
    ww kkk jw ll 120113 C
    www kk sl if 120114 D
    wwk kl so as 120114 D
    wei kk lw pz 120115 E
```

I tried to use a loop and grep but I got stuck with adding the 'A B C D E' at the end of the lines.
Here is my code,

> ```
> while read line1
> do
> Date=${line1:0:6}
> grep $Date File2
> done < File1
> ```

Please help me if someone knows how to solve this.
Thanks!

Comment: In real life, just how large are file1 and file2?

Comment: Are the file paths complete (relative or absolute)?

Comment: This looks like a job for awk.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an `awk` that does the job:

```
awk  'FNR==NR {a[$1]=$2;next} {print $0,a[$5]}' file1 file2
   aaa bb dd cc 120111 A
    ccc ss ll ee 120111 A
    sss cd ff ee 120111 A
    bbb ek lw ss 120112 B
    bbb kk ll ww 120112 B
    wwo oo kk ww 120112 B
    ww kkk jw ll 120113 C
    www kk sl if 120114 D
    wwk kl so as 120114 D
    wei kk lw pz 120115 E
```

It store the first file `file1` in array `a` using first field as index and second as data.
Then it prints out data from `file2` and using fifth field to get data from array `a`

Comment: Thank you Jotne! Very simple and fast! But can you tell me how does 'next' work in this awk command?

Comment: @LILI1234 `FNR==NR {a[$1]=$2;next}` The `FNR==NR` is only true for the first file.  The `next` prevents the other code (print) to run other than for the second file.

Comment: Thank you! Further more, if I have 2 fields in the first File1, and want to add all fields next to the second file File2, what should I do?

Comment: @LILI1234 If `file1` is some like this `120111 A More`, then this `awk  'FNR==NR {a[$1]=$2FS$3;next} {print $0,a[$5]}' file1 file2` gives `aaa bb dd cc 120111 A More`.  But if it other changes, its better to post a new question.

Comment: thank you. I think that's good enough for my question. So what is 'FS' between $2 and $3? I have 9 or 10 fields in the file1 actually.

Comment: @LILI1234 `FS` is `Field separator` -> one space.  Instead of `FS` you could have also done like this `a[$1]=$2" "$3`

Comment: I tried to store the first file `file1` in array `a` using the first AND the second field as index, and third as dat like this : `FNR==NR {a[$1FS$2]=$3;next}`. Then print out data from `file2` and using again the first AND the second field to get data from array `a` like this:`{print $0,a[$1FS$2]}` . It doesn't work. why?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect your issue is a path issue, as the grep should work fine:

```
#!/bin/bash

## validate both input files are readable
[ -r "$1" -a -r "$2" ] || {
    printf "\n error: invalid input. Usage:  %s key_file srch_file\n\n" "${0//*\//}"
}

## read each line in the first (key_file)
while read -r key ltr || [ -n "$ltr" ]; do

    ## output the grep command being used followed by the results
    printf "\n cmd: grep %s %s\n\n" "$key" "$2"
    grep "$key" "$2"

done <"$1"

exit 0
```

**output:**

```
$ bash grepvalues.sh dat/grepkey.txt dat/grepfile.txt

 cmd: grep 120111 dat/grepfile.txt

aaa bb dd cc 120111
ccc ss ll ee 120111
sss cd ff ee 120111

 cmd: grep 120112 dat/grepfile.txt

bbb ek lw ss 120112
bbb kk ll ww 120112
wwo oo kk ww 120112

 cmd: grep 120113 dat/grepfile.txt

ww kkk jw ll 120113

 cmd: grep 120114 dat/grepfile.txt

www kk sl if 120114
wwk kl so as 120114

 cmd: grep 120115 dat/grepfile.txt

wei kk lw pz 120115
```

Of course commenting the `printf` before the `grep` command produces the following results:

```
aaa bb dd cc 120111
ccc ss ll ee 120111
sss cd ff ee 120111
bbb ek lw ss 120112
bbb kk ll ww 120112
wwo oo kk ww 120112
ww kkk jw ll 120113
www kk sl if 120114
wwk kl so as 120114
wei kk lw pz 120115
```

---

**Adding Letters at end of grep output**

```
#!/bin/bash

## validate both input files are readable
[ -r "$1" -a -r "$2" ] || {
    printf "\n error: invalid input. Usage:  %s key_file srch_file\n\n" "${0//*\//}"
}

## read each line in the first (key_file)
while read -r key ltr || [ -n "$ltr" ]; do

    ## output the grep command being used followed by the results
    #printf "\n cmd: grep %s %s\n\n" "$key" "$2"
    while read -r ln; do
        printf " %s  %s\n" "$ln" "$ltr" 
    done <<<"$(grep "$key" "$2")"

done <"$1"

exit 0
```

**output:**

```
$ bash grepvalues.sh dat/grepkey.txt dat/grepfile.txt
 aaa bb dd cc 120111  A
 ccc ss ll ee 120111  A
 sss cd ff ee 120111  A
 bbb ek lw ss 120112  B
 bbb kk ll ww 120112  B
 wwo oo kk ww 120112  B
 ww kkk jw ll 120113  C
 www kk sl if 120114  D
 wwk kl so as 120114  D
 wei kk lw pz 120115  E
```

Comment: Would you like to modify this script so that it outputs the letter on the end of each line, as per the specs in the question?